# Missing websphere.jar when migrating project from WAS4 to WAS7

Tags: websphere

I have been assigned a job to compile an old Websphere(WAS4) project, so we can find out which parts of it need to be changed for the project upgrating( to WAS7).

But when I was trying to fix the jar errors, **wesphere.jar** is missing!! And WAS7 installation path never hava this jar anymore, searching google failed. And I don't like to install older WAS again to just get this jar.

please anybody can help with this, providing an WAS4 version webspere.jar???

TKX in advance!

Comment: How are you compiling? In an IDE like RAD? Ant?

Comment: sorry for not check your reply in time.                                     1st try is ant+eclipse, but the compiler complained "websphere.jar mising", should I remove the missing jar file in javabuildpath and try to locate the needed methods in other jars?

Comment: Yes, remove that jar file reference and add the new one(s). If the code isn't calling any WebSphere-specific extensions, there's a good chance j2ee.jar is the only one you'll need for compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar file itself isn't important, the classes within it are. I don't recall what was in websphere.jar, but there's a good chance that what was is now in j2ee.jar. In fact, if your code isn't using any WebSphere-specific extensions, there's a good chance j2ee.jar is the only jar from WebSphere that you'll need for compiling.

But you should be able to see what specific classes are being complained about by the compiler and if necessary search for those by opening the jar files in like WinZip.

(Keep in mind that the larger changes are the changes to J2EE and Servlet specification levels.)

Comment: Are you implying that some classes have been moved to other jar files that were supposed in websphere.jar?

Comment: Yes, WebSphere has repackaged classes into different sets of jars than in previous versions. There's no requirement that jars be organized in any particular way, just that specific classes are available somewhere.